# No signature of method java.util.LinkedHashMap.getBytes() Is applicable for argument types (String) values: [UTF-8] in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am working on a Groovy script that should send an http post request, but once it is triggered I get the following error: "Script action failed on line #16: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: no signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.getBytes() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [UTF-8]

Here is my code:

```
def post = new URL("https://someUrl.com").openConnection();
def transcript = actionJson;
def session_id = _.getSessionId();

def requestBody = 
['Session ID': session_id, 
'Transcript': transcript]
post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
post.getOutputStream().write(requestBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));
post.connect();
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if (postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

I am very new to groovy and I am not exactly sure why I am hitting this problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: `requestBody` is a `LinkedHashMap`, not a `String`.

Comment: Changed "def requestBody" to "String requestBody" and it worked like a charm! God I feel stupid , but I do expected for groovy version of the JVM to pick up and assign it to a String , guess I was wrong. Anyway , thanks again and closing the question.

Comment: Then I hope something is converting your map to JSON implicitly, because neither Java nor Groovy will do that and without further context I'd expect, that the output there is the `.toString()` of the map and not JSON?